set-builder notation and FOL formula

$S=\{x\in A|\phi(x)\}$
$\forall x (x\in S\leftrightarrow x\in A\land \phi(x))$

I wonder if 1 is just abbreviation for 2, or one has more/less/different meaning than the other.
